# overlay between 2 div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

how to overlay a div between 2 divs ?

here's what i have rn

[image: rn]

here's my code

```html
<Jumbotron style={{position: 'relative'}}>
//
</Jumbotron>
<section id="foo1">
<Container style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1}}>
//
</Container  
</section>
<section id="foo2">
<div style={{position: relative}}>
//
</div>
</section>
```

here's the result what i expect

[image: expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the overlay `div` inside another `div` and set `position: absolute`

Is this what you want? try the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/blueseal/g6zLnm97/16/)
[image]

```
<div class="test">

  <div class="div1">
   I'm div 1
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
   <div class="div-overlay">
    overlay div
   </div>
   I', div 2
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.test{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1{
  position: relative;
  display: "inline";
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

.div2{
  position: relative;
  display: "inline";
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;
}

.div-overlay{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: -25px;
  display: "inline";
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

(I wrote this code before OP posted valid image links and edited the post)

Comment: how can i make it responsive?
is it possible ?

Comment: yes, use `Media Query` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative margins:

```css
.middle {
  margin: -8px auto;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid DeepSkyBlue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px LightGray;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}
.top {
  background: DimGray;
  height: 50px;
}
.bottom {
  background: WhiteSmoke;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```